# Attach event listener to elements of a given class

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

So this may be easy but I can't get it work.
I have 3 text inputs of `filter` class. What I want is bind a function `search()` to `onkeypress` event. I know I can write it manually to every input like this `onclick="search()"` but I don't want to use inline things, just prototype functions.
My current code is:

```
<input type="text" class="filter" id="id"/>
<input type="text" class="filter" id="title"/>
<input type="text" class="filter" id="quant"/>
```

and

```
Event.observe('.filter', 'keypress', function(){ // <<< this don't work :(
    alert('yey!');
});
```

Comment: You're saying you *don't* want `prototypejs` methods? Does this mean not any? In other words, you want a complete non-library solution?

Comment: sorry. typo. I don't want to use inline `onclick="search()"`. 10x.

Comment: I re-posted my answer. I'll give an update that uses a named function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with prototypejs, but I believe you can do this:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/yAj3A/

```
$$('.filter').invoke('observe','keypress', function(){
    alert('yey!');
});
```

---

**EDIT:** Or if you wanted to use a named function, you can do that too.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/yAj3A/1/

```
function search(){
    alert('yey!');
}

$$('.filter').invoke('observe','keypress', search);
```